# How to build a custom morphological analyser for translation system

Tags: natural-language-processing

I want to build a machine translation system from English to Georgian. Georgian is a language similar (and simpler) to the Russian language. its syntax looks like **base** + **suffix**, only **suffix** changes, most of the time **base** is frozen, to describe the time the only suffix is changed. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a morphological analyser for the Georgian language, so could you link or provide useful resources to help me to build one? or can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean a tokeniser or a morphological analyser?

Comment: i mean tokenizer, i have text( georgian, i will mention english for everybody to understand), "i am dato nefaridze, and living in Georgia", i think it should split these text into words ['i', 'am' 'dato', 'nefaridze' 'and' 'live' 'ing' 'in' 'Georgia']. it should put apart living word

Comment: That's not a tokeniser. A tokeniser is mostly language-agnostic and only splits a stream of characters into words and non-words. You're looking for a morphological analyser, which can identify component parts of words, and therefore relies on knowledge about the structure of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Huggingface has a **[`Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-ka-en`](https://huggingface.co/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-ka-en)** repository with a Georgian (Ka) to English (en) model. A `tokenizer_config.json` is available

Comment: i want to build my own translation system. i think it is already trained model for translation, i need tokenizer not whole model. Also i want english to georgian, not vice versa